# Best way to create new object from existing object with certain values

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to create new object from existing object with certain values, I mean i have one onbject and i want to create a new one with only the values that i need;

For example;
Existing object

```
          data = [{
            "ID": "234324234",
            "calldate": "2018-03-25",
            "callend": "2018-03-25",
            "duration": "00:32",
            "connect_duration": "00:01",
            "progress_time": "2",
            "first_rtp_time": "2",
            "caller": "3243242342",
            "caller_domain": "XXX.XXXX.XXX",
          }, {
            "ID": "5675675",
            "calldate": "2018-03-12",
            "callend": "2018-03-12",
            "duration": "00:45",
            "connect_duration": "00:04",
            "progress_time": "2",
            "first_rtp_time": "2",
            "caller": "878678865",
            "caller_domain": "XXX.XXXX.XXX",
          }]
```

new Object required;

```
          new_object = [{
            "ID": "234324234",
            "calldate": "2018-03-25",
            "callend": "2018-03-25",
            "caller": "3243242342",
          }, {
            "ID": "5675675",
            "calldate": "2018-03-12",
            "callend": "2018-03-12",
            "caller": "878678865",
          }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like that by using `map` function

```
const new_object = data.map(({ ID, calldate, callend, caller }) => {
    return { ID, calldate, callend, caller };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer).

1. Create a class with all the properties you need
2. Convert plain (literal) objects to class (constructor) objects with proper options.

You can also look at the implementation of `plainToClass` and implement your own.